# Seamless mode in XEN?

Tags: linux, xen

Is there a seamless mode for XEN like [the solution for VirtualBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT33dAGRXIc)?

UPDATE: under e.g.: having Ubuntu 11.04 as dom0. With seamless mode I mean to integrate the guest vm's window[s] to the host's GUI.

Comment: Please have the decency to write an actual question that makes sense without having to watch the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Xen does not have a seamless mode.

You didn't mention which guest you want to run seamlessly, but if it's windows, you might be able to get a similar functionality (non-local apps appearing to run locally) by using Windows Terminal Services and RDP.

See http://www.rdesktop.org/ and http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/

If you want to run some other guest, then I believe you have fewer options (none that I'm aware of).

Comment: The same thing could be accomplished using X window forwarding or NX if the guest was *nix.

Comment: @Caleb - you're absolutely right. I completely forgot about X forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

[Bill B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/seamless-mode-in-xen/14360#14360) mentioned Terminal Services / RDP as a way to do this with windows guests. You can access just a single window and so easily mix and match windows on your primary desktop by using a network connection and a display protocol instead of the graphical XEN display.

The same effect can also be done even easier for *nix clients by using X-window forwarding.